# Visual Studio Code - How to prevent comment folding

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, fold, folding, code-folding

I love folding my code in visual studio code, but I wish I could still see my comment blocks with multiple lines. I use them for my functions and classes. Is there a way to achive this?

For example I have this piece of code:

```
    /**
    * setMinimize() - Minimize my window
    */
    setMinimize() {
        this.win.minimize()
    }
```

Now I use folding and the following happens:

```
    /**...
    setMinimize() {...
    }
```

Actually, I'd like to achieve this (so I can still see my comment block):

```
    /**
    * setMinimize() - Minimize my window
    */
    setMinimize() {...
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to say that I use the option 'fold all', or 'fold level 2'.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the comment and code block are individually foldable for me, you don't fold both at once

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to say that I use the option 'fold all', or 'fold level 2'.

Comment: Any solutions? It is really annoying! I'd love to find some workaround...

Answer (score -1):

the comment section will be visible and will not close, if you do formating you code by **ctrl+k and ctrl+f** 
and also see this example of code well formated

```
/*** This code ***/
#seo-card1 canvas,
#seo-card2 canvas {
  height: 150px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention above, that I'm using the 'fold all', or 'fold level x' options.

Comment: @borsTiHD please visit this link it may help [link](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=11815.0)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I don't know how it could help. They're talking about the Lazarus IDE. There were 2 hints I didn't know how to do in VS code. The first one: `Comments can be toggled, by making a selection, and then using the context/pop-up menu, above the fold-part of the gutter.` And the second one: `To set this, go to "Environment" - "Options" - "Code Folding".
Uncheck everything except "Procedure" and click "OK".`

Answer (score -1):

I find a way to avoid collasping multiple line comment, you can comment like this:

```
/* you can */
/* comment */
/* like this */
// #region or
// #region like
// #region this
```

This may not be a solution, but anyway it works for me. I use ctrl+k ctrl+0 to fold codes.